# highcharts not showing on heroku using python flask app

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, highcharts, flask

i have created an html which visualizes some data using highcharts. When using this html on **localhost** i can successfully see my charts. But when i use it on heroku i do not get my charts. Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<base href="https://www.highcharts.com" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

</head>
<body >

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<!--<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>-->

<!--<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>-->

<div id="container6" class="text">
<p>info:about,category,location,website,founded</p>
</div>

<div id="container" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container3" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container4" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container5" class="chart">

</div>

<div id="container7" class="chart">
<p>post message,video,photo etc.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried several solutions like copying the modules locally or impose https: insted of http: on the links.
I suppose that the issue has to do about loading the highcharts .js but i cannot figure why

Comment: Have you tried moving the inline JavaScript to the end of the file to allow the entire DOM to load first?

Comment: if you mean to move the
   
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
lines under the containers, i tried it but it not work

Comment: I also moved the javascript part under the containers code with no success

Comment: from the chrome console i found that the problem is the fact that heroku does not load the jquery. The message is the following:"
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.highcharts.com/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: i actually load the app via http and not https and the html works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that I noticed and corrected:

- Your code snippet did not have a starting `<head>` tag.
- You had an unclosed instance of `<script type="text/javascript">` right before your `</head>` tag. This was causing an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.
- I moved all of your script calls in between the `<head>` tags and gave the jQuery library an absolute URL (in order to get this to work in the snippet).

When you run the code snippet now, you'll see the expected text in the `<p>` tags. I don't see a chart, but I also don't see the code with the options to create them.

An edited version of your code snippet is below.

I hope this is helpful for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<base href="https://www.highcharts.com" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- <script src="/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

</head>
<body >

<!--<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>-->

<!--<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>-->

<div id="container6" class="text">
<p>info:about,category,location,website,founded</p>
</div>

<div id="container" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container3" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container4" class="chart">
 <p></p>
</div>
<div id="container5" class="chart">

</div>

<div id="container7" class="chart">
<p>post message,video,photo etc.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```